# CSS3 centering rule seems to prevent other elements from centering correctly

Tags: html, css

I am trying to build a simple 1-page HTML5/CSS3 site and am running into two layout-related issues that I can't seem to wrap my head around. Here is my [jsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/sc5o7h1p/).

As you can see, the **Download Info** button displays in one of three states, depending on how narrow or wide the window is:

- Either it appear below the contact emails (if the window is very narrow/mobile); or
- It appears pinned to the top (in line with the phone number) of the section it lives in if the window is a wee bit wider; or
- It appears pinned to the bottom (in line with the 2nd email) of the section it lives in if the window is full scree/maxed

I am looking for this button to exhibit the following behavior:

- If the window is very narrow (such as on a mobile browser), then I want everything to remain as-is, with the button positioned under the 2nd email; **but...**
- As soon as the window becomes a bit wider, instead of being pinned to the top of its div, I want it vertically centered (so, in line with the 1st email)

Also, there are 3 `<img>` tags at the very bottom that are currently using [placehold.it](https://placehold.it) images. I am looking to center these horizontally so that they no longer appear left-aligned and are distributed evenly over the row that they live in.

I *believe* these two issues are actually part of the same CSS/styling problem. In my massive `<style>` tag, you'll notice the following rule:

```
#home .home-inner {
    display: inline;
    float: left;
    text-align: center;
    position: relative;
    width: 100%;
    padding: 10px;
}
```

I believe that making the text center-aligned **and relative** is somehow preventing me from being able to center these other elements, but I can't figure out exactly how. Any ideas?

Comment: Look at css flexbox. Css looks way too big for such page

Comment: You should consider breaking this question down into more targeted  sections. As it stands, you have a huge file which is not easy to understand or review. Why not post the specific code for the download button in one question, and maybe the code for the 3 `img` tags in another question.

Comment: Take a look at http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve. Specially the *minimal* part. It's difficult to help you if one has to deal with a lot of code ...

Comment: orrrrr....I could just post a bounty! Boom! Problem solved. Awesome sauce!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You must use media query in CSS, and defined a specific CSS according a min-width and max-width.

see here https://jsfiddle.net/sc5o7h1p/2/

for img :

```
@media screen and (max-width: 500px) {
  .client-logo {
    width: 90%;
    height: 75% !important;
  }
  .container-img  {
    width: 90% !important;
  }
}
```

So I add new classe in your html

```
 <div class="col s4 m2 container-img">
```

And for your Btn

```
@media screen and (min-width: 500px) {
  .resume-download {
    position: relative;
    top: -117px;
    left: 272px !important;
    width:100% !important;
  }
}
```